# Printing a character at the end of a line in Python

Tags: python, printing

```
print('I "Love" yOu,end='%'')
```

Why can't I run this? It is throwing me an error. I was trying to get an error free run.

Can someone help me understand? I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: Missing single quote to end the first string, and you have a duplicate ending quote for the second string.

Comment: Also, Python 2.7 has been dead for over 3 years; it's highly recommended that new Python learners learn Python 3.

Comment: In Python 2.7, `print` is a keyword, not a function. It doesn't have keywords like `end=`.

Comment: @SuperStormer, given that the poster is using a `print` function rather than statement, it's very likely they are using Python 3+, must just be a wrong tag

Answer (score 2):

If it is Python 3.*

Try this:

```py
print("Hello world!", end='%')
```

or

This one, if you want to pass multiple strings to `print` function:

```py
print("Hello", "world!", end='%')
```

This is your example:

```py
print('I "Love" yOu', end='%')
```